# micropythonの低水準API _thread でのスレッド間通信について

Tags: python

sipeedのmaixduinoというHWでmicropythonを動作させているのですが、低水準の_thread APIをサポートしており、スレッド間のデータ通信を行いたいのですがどのようにすれば良いのでしょうか？

```
abc=0

def testThread():
    cnt=0
    while True:
        time.sleep_ms(100)
        lcd.draw_string(0,20,"cnt1:"+str(cnt))
        cnt+=1
        abc+=1
```

上記の様にglobalで宣言した変数は参照できないようでした。

Answer (score 1):

このくらいのソースであれば、`micro`とか`thread`とかは関係無く変数のスコープの問題では？
この記事のように。
[Using a global variable with a thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19790570/9014308)

参照するだけなら不要ですが、更新して他にも影響させるなら、関数の最初に`global`変数を使用する宣言が必要でしょう。

```
abc=0

def testThread():
    global abc # global変数宣言
    cnt=0
    while True:
        time.sleep_ms(100)
        lcd.draw_string(0,20,"cnt1:"+str(cnt))
        cnt+=1
        abc+=1
```

そして同一ファイル内であれば上記で良いでしょうが、ちゃんと工夫が必要な場面もあるでしょう、というのが以下の記事だと思われます。
[Global Variables](https://forum.micropython.org/viewtopic.php?t=5686)

> How to declare global variables in micropython that can be accessible from boot.py, main.py and many files.
>   creating and writing and updating file data taking time and getting into error.I want to declare only 2 variables.
>   Also want to create and freeze(compile) code for python server that listen on port for request.
>
> boot.py、main.py、および多くのファイルからアクセスできるmicropythonでグローバル変数を宣言する方法。
>   ファイルデータの作成、書き込み、更新に時間がかかり、エラーが発生します。2つの変数のみを宣言します。
>   また、リクエストをポートでリッスンするPythonサーバーのコードを作成してフリーズ（コンパイル）したいとします。

---

> Depending on your variable you can do as @stijn suggested in [this post](https://forum.micropython.org/viewtopic.php?f=16&t=6997&p=39749#p39747).
>
> 変数に応じて、この投稿で提案されている@stijnのように実行できます。

---

> If you create a variable in boot.py it will be available to main.py and to the REPL. But it won't be available to modules you import because of the way Python namespaces work: you would need explicitly to pass it to functions/methods in the module.
>
> boot.pyで変数を作成すると、main.pyとREPLで使用できるようになります。 ただし、Python名前空間が機能する方法のため、インポートするモジュールでは使用できません。モジュール内の関数/メソッドに明示的に渡す必要があります。

---

[stijn - Re: Is there an easy way to expose the value of a #define from mpconfigport.h to Python code?](https://forum.micropython.org/viewtopic.php?f=16&t=6997&p=39749#p39747)

> Something like this in main.c, after initialization and before the REPL or file execution:
>
> 何かmain.cのような、初期化の後、REPLまたはファイル実行の前に：
>
> ```
> mp_store_global(QSTR_FROM_STR_STATIC("dupterm_value"), mp_obj_new_int(MICROPY_PY_OS_DUPTERM));
> ```
>
> then when you enter the REPL or in a file, dupterm_value is in the global scope so you can acces it e.g.
>
> 次に、REPLまたはファイルに入力すると、dupterm_valueがグローバルスコープにあるため、それにアクセスできます。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。
global変数を関数内で宣言する事で参照ができました。
これでなんとか実行したいプログラムがかけそうです。
大変助かりました。